# set editors rights to someone only while script is running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, editor, temporary

I've two google spreadsheets files:

1. Input file: it's shared with collaborators. They introduce all necessary data to make a quotation
2. Output file: private file (not shared).

I've a google script that takes data from input file (1) and copy it to output file (2).

Output file (2) makes all calculations and sends one sheet to an specific e-mail with a resume of the quotation and final price.

This script works perfectly fine as long as user have editor rights to both files but I don't want to give editors rights on output file (2).

Is it possible to give editors rights to someone only while script is running?

Here is my code:

```
function INput_OUTput() {
  var INput_File = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OGB4cIfFR8GKW2Ph7W7Tx_pgF7WsHitgKJZd0s8irco/edit");
  var OUTput_File = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7G3c4-uT1_fWKk36GnJO0ga-bMpvuTt2NH1jKvDUgU/edit");
  
  const userEmail = "person@gmail.com";

  OUTput_File.addEditor(userEmail);

  var Input_File_sheet1 = INput_File.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var OUTput_File_sheet1 = OUTput_File.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var OUTput_File_calculationsheet = OUTput_File.getSheetByName('calculationsheet');

////// copy sheet////////////////////////  
  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = Input_File_sheet1.getDataRange();
  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  OUTput_File_sheet1.clear({contentsOnly: true});
  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  OUTput_File_sheet1.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);


///////////hide calculation sheets
  OUTput_File_sheet1.hideSheet();  
  OUTput_File_calculationsheet.hideSheet();

///////////send email  
  var message = {
      to: userEmail,
      subject: "Calculation result",
      body: "Hello,\n\nThanks for your ....\n\n\The Team",
      name: "MyName",
      attachments: [OUTput_File.getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("BUDGET result")]
    }
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);

OUTput_File.removeEditor(userEmail);


}
```

**Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document**

Comment: do you have edit access on both `INput_File` and `OUTput_File`? if yes, how do you execute the code?

Comment: I've edited my question and pasted real links for both files. Sharing settings are "Anyone on the internet with this link can edit". I execute the code with a drawn button with a script assigned

Answer (score 1):

### As a different approach you can deploy a Web App

You mentioned that you have 2 files:

- Input file: which is shared
- Output file: which is restricted

If you didn't want to share the **output file** but execute the `INput_OUTput()` function as you (editor). Create a standalone Google App Script and rename the function name to `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` (depending on the HTTP method you want to use) as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) says, then copy your previous function to the new function and [Deploy your App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) but keep in mind that you can set the user [who executes the Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions).

The above mentioned is how you can implement a Web App in order to manage data in a Google Apps Script without directly sharing the file because you can specify the user who runs the application regardless of the user who's requesting the PDF.

Then if you want to call doGet or doPost directly call the Web App by using the [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).